# MongoDB triggers not allowed for Serverless cluster

Tags: mongodb

I was using the free MongoDB cluster for a while with change streams to listen for documents update, insert and deletion.

Right now I'm trying their new Serverless cluster, but Changestreams are not allowed, so I decided to use Triggers, but I got this error:

**Serverless
: error finding cluster "Serverless": Serverless instance Serverless cannot be used in the cluster API.**

How am I supposed to show real-time data on frontend if I can't use Change streams and triggers neither?

Comment: This is just not the current solution for you, for obvious reasons a serverless cluster does not have "change streams", they do specify that triggers are on their roadmap but not yet supported.

If this is a deal breaker to you, then you should go back to having a dedicated server until such a feature is implemented on their serverless version.

Comment: I'll wait. I'll continue to use a dedicated cluster till that day.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert could you please post the link to the MongoDB road map. I have tried searching and I have not found it.